# How is the U-wing's cockpit laid out?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

In *Rogue One*, the U-wing appears to be piloted by two pilots at the "gunner window" at the front of the ship, at the same level or slightly above the troop bay:

[image: Cockpit, rear view]

[image: Cockpit, front view]

Seen from here, the X-wing-style cockpit on top of the craft seems to be joined to the lower window, for a wide view for the pilots.

However, all official models seem to show the pilot's area as a separate section entirely:

[image: Revell model cockpit]

[image: Lego model cockpit]

Is there a separate, unseen pilot in the movie, or is this just a last-minute change that didn't make it to the merchandise in time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The toy is wrong.**

The film's [Ultimate Visual Guide](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Rogue_One:_The_Ultimate_Visual_Guide) specifies that the U-Wing is crewed by ***two*** people, and supports up to eight passengers.

---

[image: U-Wing Layout]

As you can see in the official cutaway, the two crew members are seated side by side, just like in the movie. There is no third seat or crew member above them.

[image: cockpit layout]